# Angular - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular

I'm getting an error when I try and do an ng build on an Angular library project. Most likely something is eventually creating/calling itself, but it only fails to build for me. Everything works fine for everyone else on the team. I've looked through all the recent commits, and nothing is jumping out at me as an obvious cause. Is there a command I can run that will help me find the root cause of this?

[image: error message]

```
[error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at parseNonArrayType (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30840:28)
    at parsePostfixTypeOrHigher (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30941:24)
    at parseTypeOperatorOrHigher (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31000:20)
    at parseUnionOrIntersectionType (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31029:20)
    at parseIntersectionTypeOrHigher (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31040:20)
    at parseUnionOrIntersectionType (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31029:20)
    at parseUnionTypeOrHigher (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31043:20)
    at parseTypeWorker (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31134:24)
    at doOutsideOfContext (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:28976:20)
    at parseType (B:\WORK\widgets\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31127:20)
```

Workspace package.json dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.6",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.43",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.2.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

Library package.json dependencies

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.11",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.5.1"
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got an infinite loop somewhere, but without seeing more details it would be tough to track down. Do you have most recent dev dependencies `npm i` etc etc etc?

Comment: Yeah everything should be the most recent. Even updated node just in case.

Comment: Have you tried running it in `ng serve`, maybe that will give more feedback?. I've had this issue before, although I'm not fully sure how I fixed it. I think it might be a service calling itself or something.

Comment: I don't think I can run it with serve because its an angular library project. The computer sure things something is calling itself, but in that case why does it only fail for me, and no one else? Its quite perplexing.

Comment: Did you try compiling the app using the `ng build` command with the `--verbose` flag? (to see more details). Also which versions are you running (maybe a screenshot of the package.json)

Comment: I updated the post with the package dependencies. Tried doing an ng build with the verbose flag, but it doesn't seem to exist? Maybe that doesn't work when building libraries.

Comment: @BrianRodham were you able to fixed it? If yes, how?

Answer (score -2):

I had similar issue. The problem was that I was runnig with build flag  `--configuration production`